# Karate-Gatling: Requests with query parameter in reports are not getting aggregated

Tags: karate

I am doing a POC on karate-gatling to reuse my tests. I have referred to documentation and installed those versions. First of all awesome work as usual, very easy to setup and get going.

I am calling a feature file from **MySimualtion.scala** which has three other abstract feature calls  as follows:

```
* def tranRef = TransactionReferenceUtils.generateTransactionReferenceStartWith('09') 
* set payloadR /transaction_reference = tranRef

POST API >> /sending/v1/dm
* call read('classpath:../InitiateAbstract.feature')
* match  responseStatus == 200

GET API By Reference >> /sending/v1/dm?ref={ref}
* call read('classpath:../RetrieveByRefAbstract.feature') {ref: #(tranRef)}
* match responseStatus == 200

GET API By Id>> /sending/v1/dm/{id}
* call read('classpath:../RetrieveByIdAbstract.feature') {id: #(pmId)}
* match responseStatus == 200
```

Abstract features use **url** keyword to invoke APIs.

MySimulation.scala looks like this

```
class MySimulation extends Simulation {

  val protocol = karateProtocol(
    "/sending/v1/dm?ref={ref}" -> Nil,
    "/send/v1/dm/{id}" -> Nil,
    "/sending/v1/dm" -> Nil
  )
  
 protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getUrlAndPath()

  val create = scenario("create").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/mastercard/send/xb/Testcases/Rem1Shot/Remit1ShotWithFrwdFeesRetrieve.feature"))

  setUp(
    create.inject(rampUsers(2) during (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  )
}
```

Now the issue is, in reports GET request with {id} and POST request is getting aggregated but GET requests with ref are reported individually.

I have also tried using nameResolver with getUrlAndPath, still no luck.

I am not sure if I am missing anything here.

Note:
There was another issue where I was not able to aggregate the GET request with id by using following protocol but now its fine when I include full uri.

```
"/dm/{id}" -> Nil,
"/dm" -> Nil
```

Comment: this is too much for me to go through, follow this process if no one else helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that get request, pass a fake header and use that to control the nameResolver: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#nameresolver

I would have expected `/sending/v1/{dm}` or something like that to work.

Note that in theory you can write some custom Scala code to parse the URL and do the name resolution. If you feel this should be made easier, submit a feature request, or better still, contribute code !

Comment: Thanks! this solution worked for me. 
But further debugging, I was able to resolve this by adding param keyword in GET abstract file. Initially, the complete url was formed, stored in a variable and was passed with url keyword.